# Get primaryKey programmatically with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtsql, qsqldatabase

I try to get primaryKey programmatically and convert it to col name. this function not work as mast be.

```
QString getPrimaryFiled( const QString &tableName )
{
    QSqlDatabase m_SqlDataBase = QSqlDatabase::database(StaticConnection::getDatabaseConnectionName());
    return m_SqlDataBase.primaryIndex( tableName ).name();
}
```

But I can't find way to make it work, It's give me blank string

Comment: Have you verified that the table in question does have a primary key? And if so, what is it?

Comment: Is your table OK without using Qt?

Comment: @AndrewMedico Yes, my col that have primary key is `IdMedicalRcipeTitleLogo`.

Comment: @FinalContest yes and with Qt as will.

Comment: Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: CREATE TABLE medicalrcipetitlelogo (
  IdMedicalRcipeTitleLogo  integer,
  NameForLogo              text,
  TitleLogo                blob,
  /* Keys */
  PRIMARY KEY (IdMedicalRcipeTitleLogo)
)

Comment: [QSqlDatabase::database()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#database) is a **static** method, you are using an invalid QSqlDatabase.

Comment: @Leiaz that's my method to get Database Connection Name.

Comment: Isn't your method `getDatabaseConnectionName()` ? Doing `m_SqlDataBase.database()` doesn't change `m_SqlDataBase` from its invalid state as `database()` is a static method.

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing the following method:

> [QSqlDatabase QSqlDatabase::database(const QString & connectionName = QLatin1String( defaultConnection ), bool open = true) [static]](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#database)
>
> Returns the database connection called connectionName. The database connection must have been previously added with addDatabase(). If open is true (the default) and the database connection is not already open it is opened now. If no connectionName is specified the default connection is used. If connectionName does not exist in the list of databases, an invalid connection is returned.

You should have written this:

```
QSqlDatabase m_SqlDataBase = QSqlDatabase::database( StaticConnection::getDatabaseConnectionName() );
```

Provided that you followed the documentation properly about [addDatabase()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#addDatabase).

Comment: it's function I made to get Connection Name.

Comment: @AmrEisa: please re-read the answer carefully. It is _not_ saying that the culsprit is your database name query function.

Comment: I catch you. It's opened I'm sure from that I Edit my first post to make code more clear.

Comment: @AmrEisa: of course it is not working since you do not follow the documentation above.

Comment: I do and It's work by this call m_SqlDataBase.primaryIndex( tableName ).fieldName(0); but I don't need this it's static call for fieldName(0)

Comment: And I test it with mysql and Sqlite and Connection work fine but it's and it's give me blank string ""